# html buttons change div content or toggle it again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to know how to create buttons which can change the content inside a div and if the last clicked button (actual content) is clicked again instead of change it should clear the div.

So far I got the code to create and change the content like this:

HTML

```
<button onclick="changeNavigation('bl1')">Techniker</button>
<button onclick="changeNavigation('bl2')">Übersetzer</button>
<button onclick="changeNavigation('bl3')">Qualitychecker</button>

<div id="text_content"></div>

<div id="bl1">
    <p>This is text 1</p>
</div>
<div id="bl2">
    <p>This is text 2</p>
</div>
<div id="bl3">
    <p>This is text 3</p>
</div>
```

JS

```
function changeNavigation(id) {
    document.getElementbyId('text_content').innerHTML= document.getElementbyId(id).innerHTML;
}
```

With this code so far I can make the content inside the div change by clicking the bottons. But once the box has been filex I can only change the inside content. If I click the button from the actual content again nothing happens but I'd like to clear the content.

Can maybe anyone explain me or link me the name of such a funtion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, you know how to get the innerHTML of the button and the div.  A quick equality check would let you know if they are equal or not.  Have you tried something like that?

Comment: Im not really sure what you're trying to get here? If you click a nav item twice to clear the div? 
Could you try explaining exactly what you want to happen again?

Comment: They want if you click any of the buttons, it will update the text in the `text_content`.  If you click the same button twice, the `text_content` should be empty. @Daryl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not really sure what you're trying to get here? If you click a nav item twice to clear the div?

If so try something like this

```
function changeNavigation(id) {
    var textContent = document.getElementbyId('text_content'),
        containerDiv = document.getElementbyId(id);

    if(textContent.innerHTML === containerDiv.innerHTML){
        textContent.innerHTML = '';
    } else {
        textContent.innerHTML = containerDiv.innerHTML
    }
}
```

What we're doing here is checking if the text_content is the same value as the div you're getting the content from. if so then empty it.

Comment: Thank you mate! That was exactly what I was looking for! :)
I tried comparing the buttons but I didn't knew that I could compare the content like this!
Awesome!

Comment: *but I didn't knew that I could compare the content like this*  Can I ask why not?  If you can set X = Y, then it should be an fairly quick assumption that you can also do X == Y or X === Y.  @Akagex

Comment: Maybe new to programming in general? Gotta start somewhere!